# Automotive relay pin numbers

Tags: relay

I have the following relay. The pins are numbered 1, 2, 3 and 5, rather than the more usual 85, 86, 30 and 87.

I would like the following confirmed:

- 1 = 85
- 2 = 86
- 3 = 30
- 5 = 87

Thanks

[image: Relay]

Comment: I wonder where the datasheet is and the 4th spade pin. Must be a hidden chassis gnd thread underneath

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 the 4th pin is just visible - the end just shows clear of the middle one...

Comment: There are only 4 pins and no other threads

Answer (score 2):

The numbering system is given in [DIN 72552](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_72552).

[image]

[image]

- 1 = 85 (can probably be swapped with 86)
- 2 = 86

Since it's just a normally open contact ...

- 3 = 30 I would call this 87 as it is the 'hinge'/common.
- 5 = 87 I would call this 87b.

Comment: So 2 is hidden. Coil -.

Comment: Thanks, I came across this myself but wanted to double check